# Баг в TimePicker. Не работают функции setHour, setMinute

Tags: android

Судя по всему наткнулся на баг в TimePicker. После взаимодействия пользователя с виджетом не работают функции setHour, setMinute.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mButton;
    private TimePicker mTimePicker;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
                mTimePicker.setMinute(minute);

                Log.v(TAG, "onClick: " + hour + "=>" + mTimePicker.getHour());
                Log.v(TAG, "onClick: " + minute + "=>" + mTimePicker.getMinute());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Как проявляется:

1. Запускаю приложение (мое время: 13:21)
2. Меняю время в виджете пальецем (21:21)
3. Нажимаю на кнопку "Сброс"

Результат:время не сбрасывается на 13:21

Логи:

> 03-30 13:18:05.765 30923-30923/ru.neverdark.timepickerproblem
>   V/MainActivity: onClick: 13=>21 03-30 13:18:05.765
>   30923-30923/ru.neverdark.timepickerproblem V/MainActivity: onClick:
>   18=>18

Как-нибудь это можно обойти? Мне нужна функция сброса времени на текущее время устройства по действию пользователя (нажатию кнопки).

Comment: на каком api (эмулятор или девайс) проверяете? setHour/setMinute доступны с 23. попробуйте setCurrentHour/setCurrentMinute

Comment: Тесты на android 6. Проблема здесь не версионности. При использовании устаревших setCurrentHour и setCurrentMinute результат остается неизменным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вдруг кому будет полезно:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int currentMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        fixValues();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mTimePicker.setHour(currentHour);
            mTimePicker.setMinute(currentMinute);
        } else {
            mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(currentHour);
            mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(currentMinute);
        }
    }
});

private void fixValues() {
    // bug is not reproducible in APIs 24 and above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) return;
    try {
        int hour, minute;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            hour = mTimePicker.getHour();
            minute = mTimePicker.getMinute();
        } else {
            hour = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
            minute = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
        }

        Field mDelegateField = mTimePicker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDelegate");
        mDelegateField.setAccessible(true);
        Class<?> clazz;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            clazz = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePickerClockDelegate");
        } else {
            clazz = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate");
        }
        Field mInitialHourOfDayField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mInitialHourOfDay");
        Field mInitialMinuteField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mInitialMinute");
        mInitialHourOfDayField.setAccessible(true);
        mInitialMinuteField.setAccessible(true);
        mInitialHourOfDayField.setInt(mDelegateField.get(mTimePicker), hour);
        mInitialMinuteField.setInt(mDelegateField.get(mTimePicker), minute);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43161326/2655596